# Positioning and rotating a mesh in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to build something like this site hero-unit: http://www.nodeplus.com.cn/

My approach is to make a temporary 2d canvas, print out my message to it, scan the pixels and then use them to position the meshes in 3d space:

```
 // STEP 1: if a pixel is detected on every gridX / gridY step, put it in the pos array
          for (y = 0; y <= height; y += gridY) {
            for (x = 0; x <= width; x += gridX) {
              if (buffer32[y * width + x]) {
                positions.push({x: x, y: y});
              }
            }
          }
```

then i put them in 3d space accordingly

```
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              pos = positions[i];
              shape = new Shape({
                x: pos.x / 10,
                y: -pos.y / 10,
                z: Math.random() * 4
              });
              shape.init(scene);
              shapes.push(shape);
            }
```

Thats all fine and good, but i want them to be positioned at the scene center.
Because of the way im scanning the 2d canvas and getting the positions from there (starting at 0, 0), they get some very weird positioning in 3d space with three.js (because i have pixels that are positioned like {x: 1600, y:500} on bigger screens)

I had to put a strange camera.lookAt position just to look at it, something like:

```
camera.position.set(100, 0, 80);
          camera.lookAt({
            x: 95,
            y: -50,
            z: scene.position.z
          });
```

This kinda works for now, but its not a good option for me. I want to rotate the camera around the letters and dont want to rotate it around some weird position like this.

You can check out the code here:

```js
var heroUnit = (function(self) {

        function Shape(pos) {
          this.pos = pos;
          this.mesh = null;
          this.radius = 2 + Math.random() * 2;
          this.speed = 0.4 + Math.random() * 0.4;
        }

        Shape.prototype.init = function(scene) {
          var geometry, material, mesh,
              v1, v2, v3;

          geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

          v1 = new THREE.Vector3(this.pos.x - this.radius / 2, this.pos.y - this.radius / 2, this.pos.z - this.radius / 2);
          v2 = new THREE.Vector3(this.pos.x + this.radius / 2, this.pos.y - this.radius / 2, this.pos.z - this.radius / 2);
          v3 = new THREE.Vector3(this.pos.x + this.radius / 2, this.pos.y + this.radius / 2, this.pos.z + this.radius / 2);

          geometry.vertices.push(v1);
          geometry.vertices.push(v2);
          geometry.vertices.push(v3);

          geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
          geometry.computeFaceNormals();

          material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF});
          mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

          this.mesh = mesh;

          this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;

          //this.mesh.scale.set(Math.random() * 20, Math.random() * 20, Math.random() * 20);
          this.mesh.rotation.set(0, 0, 0)
          scene.add(this.mesh);

        }

        var width, height,
            aspectRatio, pov,
            near, far,
            scene, camera,
            renderer, 
            effectPositions,
            shapes, light;

        function init(string) {
          // constants
          width = window.innerWidth;
          height = window.innerHeight;
          pov = 45;
          aspectRatio = width / height;
          near = 0.1;
          far = 1000;

          // three.js specific stuff
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(pov, aspectRatio, near, far);
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
          light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x000000, 0.6);

          // containers
          effectPositions = getPixels(string);
          shapes = [];

          // set up light
          light.position.set(100, 0, 200);
          light.castShadow = true;
          scene.add(light);

          // set size to renderer, color it in dark blue & append it to dom
          renderer.setSize(width, height);
          renderer.setClearColor(0x17293a);
          document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

          // set up camera
          camera.position.set(100, 0, 80);
          camera.lookAt({
            x: 50,
            y: -50,
            z: scene.position.z
          });
          scene.add(camera);

          generateShapes(effectPositions);

        }

        // generate 3d shapes according to our 2d positions array
        function generateShapes(positions) {
          var i, n, len, 
              pos, shape,
              maxIterations

          len = positions.length;
          maxIterations = 2;

          for (n = 0; n <= maxIterations; n++) {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              pos = positions[i];
              shape = new Shape({
                x: pos.x / 10,
                y: -pos.y / 10,
                z: Math.random() * 4
              });
              shape.init(scene);
              shapes.push(shape);
            }
          }

        }

        // get 2d positions
        function getPixels(string) {
          var canvas, ctx, 
              idata, buffer32,
              x, y,
              gridX, gridY,
              positions;

          //make temp canvas on which to draw and get pixel data
          canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          positions = [];
          string = string.toUpperCase().split("").join(String.fromCharCode(8202));

          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = height;

          //document.body.appendChild(canvas);

          ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
          ctx.font = 'bold 260px Arial';
          ctx.fillText(string, width / 2 - ctx.measureText(string).width / 2, height / 2);

          idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
          buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);
          gridX = gridY = 14;

          // if a pixel is detected on every gridX / gridY step, put it in the pos array
          for (y = 0; y <= height; y += gridY) {
            for (x = 0; x <= width; x += gridX) {
              if (buffer32[y * width + x]) {
                positions.push({x: x, y: y});
              }
            }
          }

          // return pos array
          return positions;

        }

        // render function
        function render(ts) {
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
          //    shape.mesh.position.x = shape.dist + (Math.sin(ts / 500)) * shape.speed;
          })
        }

        return {
          init: init,
          render: render
        }

      }(heroUnit || {}))

      // init our program
      heroUnit.init('100');

      // redraw each frame
      (function drawFrame(ts) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
        heroUnit.render(ts);
      }());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.js"></script>
```

Any ideas and suggestions are more then welcome, cheers

Comment: why dont you subtract half your canvas22 dimensions from the (x,y) positions of your letters?